# Native iOS Oracle Database Connection

Tags: ios, database, oracle11g, xamarin

I am currently developing a native iOS (from 8.0 in swift) application for a customer of my company. One of his requirements is that the mobile application have to connect **directly** to a remote oracle database (11g 2.0.3). Yes, I know this is a **really really bad idea** and we should not do that, but our customer **explicitly wants this** and doesn't want any additional infrastructure.

**So please don't advise me to do this over an approriate web service.**

I already seeked through the Internet several times to find a suitable solution. There appears to be a ODBC driver [ODBCRouter](http://odbcrouter.com/Main), but as far as I could see, this driver is really really really outdated and won't be fit in my project. Even the [native web services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_web_services.htm) introduced in oracle 11g do not appear to be a viable solution for our customer.

We also have experience in Xamarin but even there seems to be no solution for my problem. I tried to install the *Official Oracle ODP.NET Managed Driver* NuGet package, but that doesn't work because of the iOS target.

I would be most pleased if anyone has an idea and can help me :)

Comment: I can help, give me your clients' # and I will tell them NO....... otherwise you might want to see if you can connect with Glimpse I/O LLC as they appear to be doing it natively(?) : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oracle-mobile-database-client/id397643049?mt=8

Comment: Keep in mind anything you custom build to support this is going to need updating to keep it running. I'm sure you know that already. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply! I mailed Glimpse I/O LLC, perhaps they can help me.